# /etc/sudoers file help in giving access to all command in UNIX

Tags: linux, sudo, su

`/etc/sudoers` file help in giving access to all command in UNIX. I read it  has rules specified  like `#root ALL=(ALL|ALL):ALL` that specifies root accesses.

My question is when we execute a command when does this `/etc/sudoers` file check accesses and does `/etc/group` also have any role?

Comment: Hmmm....there is SO much out there on sudo, including the man page which has a LOT of easy to understand information.  What have you looked at and what difficulty are you having in understanding after looking at this information.

Comment: I did not understand the role of /etc/group in sudo

Answer (score 1):

It only checks access when you issue a specific command: `sudo`.

It doesn't check for just any command whether you have the right to run it with root privileges. The `sudo` elevates your privileges then runs the other commands as such, without needing any additional checks.

Quite often the setup is such that you have to be member of the `sudo` group (e.g. Debian) or `wheel` group (e.g. CentOS) to be able to use `sudo`, which is better maintainable than having specific names/restrictions in the `/etc/sudoers` file itself.